# Non interrupting wide items in Masonry JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, masonry

I'm using Masonry as layout engine. My base grid items are squares, (25% width in this example) while the wide items have a 100% width.

Until now zero problems, but I would like the wide items to not interrupt the flow of items, so there aren't so many blank spaces left. Is that possible?

Here is the code:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/masonry-layout@4/dist/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<style>
  .grid-sizer, .grid-item { width: 25%; height: 25vw; border: 1px; border-color: black; border-style: solid; margin: 0; box-sizing: border-box; text-align: center; font-size: 60px; color: darkgray; font-family: sans-serif; padding-top: 50px;}
  .grid-item--width2 { width: 100%; }
</style>
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-sizer"></div>
  <div class="grid-item">1</div>
  <div class="grid-item">2</div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item--width2">3</div>
  <div class="grid-item">4</div>
  <div class="grid-item">5</div>
</div>
<script>
$('.grid').masonry({
  itemSelector: '.grid-item',
  columnWidth: '.grid-sizer',
  percentPosition: true
})
</script>
```

[Current layout (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QwMD3.png)

[Expected result (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8V6e.png)

I still do not know how to achieve the expected results in Masonry, but there is a pure CSS way to do it: a grid, with **grid-auto-flow** set to **dense.**